# Whic spec define the ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

First at all, I want know the difference between the $(document).ready and the $(window).load, then I know this.

But, I have some new questions.what is the ready event, what is the detail. what is the load event.

I have find the description of load event in the HTML spec.

But I can't find the description of the ready event.

Comment: There is no jQuery spec.

Comment: @Oolong, if you want to understand the difference between `ready` and `load` you should [read the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ready()` is an abstraction implemented by jQuery based on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

`load()` (*Note this jQuery method is depreciated*) is based on [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

The MDN articles link to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript window is one of core object and defines several useful events e.g. onload, before jQuery comes, if want to execute any code, once DOM is loaded completely, we use `window.onload` event

There is a problem with `window.onload` , it not exactly executed when DOM is loaded but it executes after all content including big images are loaded completely. Browser normally delay executing onload code, until all page content is loaded, because of this user can see significant delay between they first see the page and the time that code inside onload get executed, this delay is particularly notable, if your page content heavy images, flash videos or other heavy content with low bandwidth internet connection.

`jQuery` solves this problem by introducing ready event, you might have seen code like below in several JavaScript files or HTML pages :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Inside jQuery ready method");
});
```

here `$()` is a shortcut for `jQuery()` function, and we wrap document object into jQuery object to use `ready()` method. We are passing an anonymous function to `ready()` method, which will be executed once DOM is loaded. It doesn't wait till all DOM content available e.g. images. By the way, instead of using `$(document).ready()` function, you can also use following short-cut, which has same effect :

```
$(function() {
   alert("shortcut for document.ready method in jQuery");
});
```

Apart from faster execution, one of the key advantage of jQuery ready method over JavaScript window onload event is that, you can use them multiple times in your page, unlike onload event, which can only be bind to a single function. Browser will ensure to execute all document.ready code to execute in the order, they are specified in the HTML page.

Hope this will be useful for you.

Thanks